# Issues with Chrome Remembering Password on Reset page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

On our website (MVC Razor, C#) we have a login page with password reset functionality. This sends the user an email with a reset link. When they click this they are taken to a page where they enter their email address, new password and a password confirmation. The issue we have is Chrome offers to remember their login details using their email address. However this is invalid as the user logs in with a username and password, not their email.

On another page in the site where the user can edit their personal information we also have fields where the password can be updated. With this we add an input[type=text] field containing their username just prior to the first password field. This is moved far to the left via css. When the user clicks save the browser will offer to update their login information, this time with the correct details (username and password). Prior to adding the offset field it would offer to remember the last line in the users address along with the password.

While this offset username field approach also works on our password reset page in Firefox, it doesn't in Chrome. Chrome appears to differentiate between pages that edit data and those that create new information. On the page where the user edits their data Chrome offers to *update* their login details. On our password reset page however it always asks if the user wants to *save* this information. In testing I removed the css that offset the username field, making it visible again. If I left the username field with the pre populated data and saved this made no difference. However when I manually edited the data, re-entering what was already there, Chrome offered to save the correct information (username and password).

So I tried 2 things:
1. To add Javascript logic to try and simulate the field being edited manually. I used jQuery and tried calling combinations of keypress(), keydown() and change().
2. Adding fields that were offset to the left containing prefilled data so that Chrome might think this was a page being 'edited'.

Neither approach worked. If anyone has any ideas or recommendations this would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution we came up with. We moved the offset field and 2 password fields to the top of the page. This made the offset username input the first field in the page. We then wrapped these fields in a div element. We also wrapped the email field in (separate) div. Finally we added css to relatively position the 2 wrapper divs so that the appearance of the page was the same as before. This time Chrome offered to remember the correct values.

Note that we needed to edit the tabindexes for the form fields to ensure the tab key worked as expected.

Just to add, we had another issue that was similar. Namely we had a couple of pages where we require the user to enter their password (normally as the last field in the page) as part of the verification for the process they were completing. This was required even though they were already logged in. Though these pages aren't login forms most browsers would offer to update/remember the information, but with a completely invalid username once again.

The solution we came up with for this was to add a hidden form field just below the password field. When the submit button was clicked we copy the password to the hidden field. When the actual form submit event occurs we check if the form is valid and, if so, replace the password field in the page with a plain text field with a series of '•' characters in it. As there was no password field in the page when the form was submitted the browser no longer offered to remember the login information.